# Auto log activities to CLOSED opportunities?

Tags: email, einstein, lightning-for-gmail

Our *current* way of doing things in SFDC, has customer success working off of the opportunity as opposed to the account object. The opp has information they need, along with the fact its related to some custom objects related to implementation and training of the product we sell. All that being said, I'm getting several notifications (and have for months, but haven't looked into it that hard until now,) that communication isn't being automatically logged on the opp that a contact/email address is related to. In some research I believe I've found that the whole auto activity capture will only auto log to an opp within 60 days of it being closed. Does this sound correct to anyone else? I'm wondering if we'll need to either manually log emails via the 'lightning for gmail' chrome extension, or the less favorable option, to figure out a way for us to work off of accounts instead.

Comment: How are you currently logging activities? Salesforce rolls up Activities to related Accounts (from the Contact), but not to related Opportunities, unless you are using some customization or a sync tool that adds such an association.

Comment: @DavidReed Customer success folks have just been sending emails via a tab of Gmail in their browser. You say Salesforce should be rolling up activities to related accounts, should that be done if an email is sent via gmail? Ex. just to make sure I understand you:  

Account 1 | 
jonsmith@example.com is a related contact to Account 1  |
jonsmith is a contact role on Opportunity 1  |

Customer support sends an email via Gmail to jonsmith@example.com  |
This 'activity' should show up on Account 1  |

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Every Activity (Task and Event) in Salesforce has three linking fields:

- `WhoId` (called "Name" in the user interface), which links to either a Contact or Lead. (If you're using Shared Activities, it could be linking to multiple Contacts).
- `WhatId` (called "Related To" in the user interface), which links to some other record to which the Activity is related. This may be an Account, an Opportunity, a custom object, and so forth.
- `AccountId`. Salesforce [calculates a link to an Account](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000194177&type=1) to which the Activity will roll up, based upon the content of the `WhoId` and `WhatId` fields. If `WhatId` is an Opportunity, `AccountId` will be its Account.

There isn't built-in functionality that rolls up Tasks and Events against Opportunities unless they are explicitly associated to the Opportunity via the Related To lookup.

If users log Activities through the Salesforce UI, they should select the Opportunity as their Related To, or begin logging from a related list or Quick Action on the Opportunity record page.

If users log Activities via an external connector, such as a GSuite sync or Cirrus Insight, they may or may not have the option to specify a Related To object (depending on the sync application and its configuration). If the sync application doesn't provide this functionality, custom work would need to be done to locate and associate an Opportunity.

There isn't a date range or a Closed/Open status "filter" in core Sale Cloud functionality related to Activity association or roll-up mechanics, but there is in [Einstein Activity Capture](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000249934&type=1). If that's the product you're using, the limitation is there:

> If Einstein Activity Capture adds emails and events to a contact or person account that’s associated with an opportunity’s contact role, those emails and events are also added to the opportunity. Einstein Activity Capture only adds emails and events that occurred in an opportunity's date range to the opportunity.

The linked document above includes details of the calculation of the date range for Closed and Open Opportunities, which are handled a little differently.

Comment: thank you so much for the nicely formatted response. I just tested it with a brand new account/opp/contact with a close date of 9/1/18. I sent a test email, it showed up automatically on the account, but not the opp. I moved the closed date to 12/1/18, and the email showed up on the opp - seems because it was now within the 60 day window. That 60 day limitation is annoying!

Comment: @DevinPearman Are you using Einstein Activity Capture?

Comment: yeah I am using the 'standard einstein activity capture', that I believe every org has 100 licenses of.

Comment: @DevinPearman Got it. I did not grasp the significance of the `einstein` tag on your question; apologies. That appears to be a behavior/limitation of the EAC product. See update.

Comment: thanks for the update and link, that is what I was afraid of. This all points to the fact that we shouldn't be working off of the opp object, but rather the account.